# Where Generic T is implementation of Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net-core

Given the following classes and hierarchy:

```
public abstract class AbsractClass<T>
{ 
    public T Id { get; private set; }
}

public class ImplementationA : AbsractClass<Guid> { }

public class ImplementationB : AbsractClass<int> { }
```

What constraint should I be using in **where** clause/constraint to specify that generic T must be implementation of AbsractClass. Which would mean that Entity  would accept either ImplementationA or ImplementationB.

```
public abstract class Entity<T> // where : T ?
{ 
}
```

Is this something that is possible or should I be using interfaces instead?

Comment: You should one more parameter to entity class, like `Entity<T, U>` and use `where T : AbstractClass<U>`. If it fits your design, of course

Comment: Sorry, just curious, in your application is there any code which consume `AbstractClass<T>` or you have it just to save on typing common property `id`?

Comment: It was pretty stupid idea that I didn't end up using, but still, in the end I learned a new thing thanks to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add two generic parameters to make it work:

```
public abstract class Entity<T, TKey>  where T : AbstractClass<TKey>
{
}
```

Generic interfaces would behave the same way.